# Type checking MaterialTopTabNavigation screen's navigation, route and props in React Native

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation, react-props, typechecking

I have a Material Top Tabs Navigator setup with 3 screens (Shipping, Payment and Confirm), I am passing and order object props from Shipping to Payment on a click of CONFIRM button and from Payment to Confirm on a click of CONFIRM button so I will also need access to navigation and route props.
with my current setup I am getting typescript error on my createMaterialTopTabNavigator file. Please see my code and images bellow. Thank you.

types.tsx

```
    import { MaterialTopTabScreenProps, MaterialTopTabNavigationProp,
    } from "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs";
    import { RouteProp } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { order } from "./utils/interface";
    
 export type CheckoutTopTabParamList = {
  Shipping: undefined;
  Payment: { order: order; };
  Confirm: { order: order; };
};
    
    export type CheckoutTopTabProps<Screen extends keyof CheckoutTopTabParamList> =
      MaterialTopTabScreenProps<CheckoutTopTabParamList, Screen>;

I also tried this method too:

    export type CheckoutTopTabProps<T extends keyof CheckoutTopTabParamList> = {
      navigation: MaterialTopTabNavigationProp<CheckoutTopTabParamList, T>;
      route: RouteProp<CheckoutTopTabParamList, T>;
    };
```

My Shipping screen:Checkout.tsx

```
import { CheckoutTopTabProps } from "../../../types";
import { setOrder } from "../../../redux/slices/orderItemsSlice";

const Checkout = ({ navigation }: CheckoutTopTabProps<"Shipping">) => {

  const checkOut = () => {
    navigation.navigate("Payment", { order });
  };

return (

  <FormContainer>
   <KeyboardAwareScrollView>
    ---------------------
    ---------------------
    ---------------------
    <View style={{ width: "80%", alignItems: "center" }}>
          <Button title="Confirm" onPress={checkOut} />
        </View>)

     </FormContainer>
    </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
  );

}
```

My Payment screen: Payment.tsx

```
import { CheckoutTopTabProps } from "../../../types";

export type PaymentProps = {
  order: order;
  navigation: CheckoutTopTabProps<"Payment">["navigation"];
  route: CheckoutTopTabProps<"Payment">["route"];
};

const Payment = ({ order, navigation, route }: PaymentProps) => {
return (

<View>
<View>
--------------------
--------------------
--------------------
<View style={{ marginTop: 60, alignSelf: "center" }}>
          <Button
            title={"Confirm"}
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Confirm", { order })} 
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>

)
}
```

My createMaterialTopTabNavigator file: CheckoutTopTabNavigator.tsx

```
    import React from "react";
    import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs";
    
    // Screens
    import Checkout from "../screens/Cart/Checkout/Checkout";
    import Payment from "../screens/Cart/Checkout/Payment";
    import Confirm from "../screens/Cart/Checkout/Confirm";
    import { RootState } from "../redux/store";
    import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
    
    const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();
    
    function MyTabs() {
    
        const order = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.orderItems.order);
      return (
        <Tab.Navigator>
          <Tab.Screen name="Shipping" component={Checkout} />
          <Tab.Screen name="Payment" component={Payment} />
          <Tab.Screen name="Confirm" component={Confirm} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
      );
    }
    
    export default function CheckoutTopTabNavigator() {
      return <MyTabs />;
    }
// My error is on this screen:
```

Please see the images bellow for the errors:
[image: Please click here to see the error]
[image: Please click here to see the error]
[image: Please click here to see the error]

The last line on the error is (MaterialTopTabNavigationOptions, MaterialTopTabNavigationEventMap>')

I want to mention that, I have also tried to pass the order props using redux state like this:

```
const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

function MyTabs() {

    const order = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.orderItems.order);
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Shipping" component={Checkout} />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Payment"
        children={(props) => <Payment order={order} {...props} />}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Confirm"
        children={() => <Confirm order={order} />}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

The entire code can be found on my github link: https://github.com/obomheire/eazyPick-client/tree/default-local-branch on the default-local-branch.

Thank you for your support .